# How to get the gradients of non trainable variables during the backward propagation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

The API function `compute_gradients` in optimizers of Tensorflow only returns the gradients of trainable variables such as weights or biases of each layer with trainable parameters.
Is it possible to get the gradients of non trainable variables such as dL/dx or dL/dy of each layer?
If there is no API function corresponding to this functionality, is it possible to obtain the gradients of these variables manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can compute the gradient explicitely with [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1., trainable=False)
y = x**2
g = tf.gradients(y, [x])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print(g[0].eval())
# 2.0
```

Amusingly, this also works if `x` is a constant:

```
x = tf.constant(1.)
```

Comment: This is how we calculate the dy/dx, but for the gradients of dL/dy and dL/dx, we need to apply the chain rule. Does that mean the final results have to be done manually?

Comment: @doody1986 Replace `y` by any tensor that eventually depends on `x`. The chain rule is calculated automatically by tensorflow -- it is actually one of its major feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I am concerned, the chain rule can only be applied implicitly when we actually train a network model by calling a selected optimizer. It seems to me that the `tf.gradients` is a function that has nothing to do with the optimizers (I might be wrong, so please correct me if so). My another question would be can I use the `tf.gradients` to obtain the gradients implicitly calculated by the optimizers?

Comment: I am starting to get what you were saying about the usage of the `tf.gradients`. I can replace the y with the loss, and the output of each layer as x, and then I can get all gradients of them.